# Why does nesting an inline within a block create a 1px gap at the bottom?

Tags: css

I have a simple structure

```
<nav>
    <span>
        <a href="#">A</a>
        <a href="#">B</a>
        <a href="#">C</a>
    <span>
<nav>
```

and I go Godzilla on the css, e.g.

```
margin:0px; padding:0px; vertical-align:bottom; box-sizing:border-box;
```

But no matter what I try there is always this really cool 1px gap at the bottom of the element. Why is it there and how would you make it go away if you were me?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6b98/)

[image]

Comment: You talking about the very bottom or the `ACKK TAR` above the `REBAR FOO SMARs AK MAR EN GAR`?

Comment: The orange line underneath REBAR FOO SMARs AK MAR EN GAR

Comment: I don't see it on the fiddle. Even when zooming in. What browser are you on?

Comment: Nope. Not on Chrome 33 either.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Chrome 33.. take a look at this example zoomed in.. http://jsfiddle.net/PU4KM/

Comment: Chrome 33. Not seeing anything.@JoshCrozier  http://jsbin.com/cawokoti/1

Comment: @Shrink Interesting. I get this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Da2kb.jpg Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m .. Win7

Comment: That's weird. http://i.imgur.com/EUlbWcd.png @JoshCrozier

Comment: @Shrink I guess it's a Mac/Win Chrome inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to make the `<span>` element `inline-block`. This will remove the gap

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ84R/)

```
nav > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively, a display of `block` works too. The point is that it is no longer a pure `inline` element.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean, it does appear (on Firefox) without zooming in closely. I believe the problem is the default `line-height` given to text in browsers, which results in a bit of extra space between text lines.

With some experimentation, I found that adding these styles works:

```
nav {
    font-size:16px; /* Default font size in Firefox, but specify just in case */
    line-height:18px;
}
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6b98/2/) to demonstrate it. Seems to work properly in Firefox and Chrome. Let me know if you have any problems, though. Hope this helps!